# Time Zones and Offset from specific Hour

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get the users time in their respective local time as many number hours is it from a specific hour of the day.

So for example, the hour is constant and 4PM UTC

The string will look like this :

Your package will be ready 11PM UTC (User time in hour/time of day + local time abbreviation)

So :

> Your package will be ready 11PM UTC (7PM EST)

I'm having a hard time calculating the time from 11PM UTC.

Here is what I have:

```
float timezoneoffset = ([[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] /3600.0);
//Gets time zone hours away from GMT/UTC time in this case -4
```

I know how to get a date since date, but in my case it will always be 11PM UTC or whatever the number is set to. So how do you get date from a certain hour of any day (always constant though, always 11PM or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Welp after playing around with it for a couple hours this is what I came up with.

```
[NSDate date]
```

Automatically by default is UTC or GMT time. So from there I just used `NSDateComponents` to force a date start at the time I wanted and subtracted/added from the timezoneoffset value:

```
 float timezoneoffset = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setHour:23];
    [components setMinute:0];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

    NSDate *maintenanceDateTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSDate *localTimeFromUTC = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:timezoneoffset sinceDate:maintenanceDateTime];

    NSDateFormatter *utc_formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [utc_formatter setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
    [utc_formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```